# Create a custom workflow with SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I'm wanting to create a custom workflow that will run on list items in a SharePoint site.

Requirements are:

1. Administrator initiates new task
2. Email is generated to field users telling them to respond
3. Field users respond and change item state to reviewed
4. Administrator reviews and marks item closed, or:
5. Field user doesn't respond before deadline, and gets a warning email based on due date.

Comment: Are you using SharePoint out of the box, SharePoint Designer, or some other tool?

Comment: You need to be more specific. What tool or language? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint Designer. 
Under your list you will create new Workflow 2010. Open and edit this workflow and add new action "Start Approval process".

Here is example: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-the-task-process-editor-for-approval-workflows-8680b4a4-36b1-441c-b070-e515976078aa